# Docusaurus 2 inclusion of a video file in a markdown file

Tags: markdown, docusaurus

Using Docusaurus for help documentation. I can include images, gifs, and reference a youtube video (use iframe). But it is not clear to me how to include a video in a markdown file.

I am expecting the video to be in my repo (i.e. src="./assets/my-video.mp4" type=video/mp4").

There has been discussion on [this issue](https://github.com/facebook/docusaurus/issues/1165), but I have not been able to find a simple example referencing a video.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to install the `react-player`, create a file with `.mdx` extension and add the video.

**1)** Install the `react-player`:

> npm install react-player

**2)** In your file, for example `Intro.mdx`, insert at the top (bellow the `---` if present):

```
import ReactPlayer from 'react-player'
```

then insert the video, wherever you want it:

```
<ReactPlayer playing controls url='video.mp4' />
```

**IMPORTANT**

1. I am having some trouble trying to render videos using relative path. So maybe better putting them inside the `static` folder, then calling using `<ReactPlayer playing controls url='/video.mp4' />` (note the `/` before the filename).
2. I forgot to change the extension to `mdx`. But it is working fine with `md` extension files.

---

**REFERENCES**

1. I followed the link you provide to learn how to do it
2. https://github.com/facebook/docusaurus/issues/489
3. https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-player

**NOTE:** Use the reference #3 to learn more about the react-player! There are a lot of cool stuff you can use on the video player.

---

**DISCLAIMER**

Like *endiliey* said in your [reference link](https://github.com/facebook/docusaurus/issues/1165), it is super easy — for those who are familiarized with the technology. Which was not my case… But was fun to learn about it!

Comment: Thanks for the info. Yes, it is quite easy "once you know the steps".  I got hung up on the path for the mp4 file.

Comment: Doesn't work. The play button doesn't start the video\

Comment: @Pian0_M4n, have you put your video inside your static folder? I had problems using relative links. (check the "IMPORTANT" section in my answer)

Comment: Thanks @D.Kastier this is the answer I followed, although I had to add a bit more things, since my BaseUrl wasn´t '/'. I added an answer as a suggestion for your method, for people tha need relative paths.

Answer (score 7):

You can use `react-player` library as D.Kastier suggested, but you can also use a `video` tag.

### 0. What doesn't work

```html
<video controls>
  <source src="./up%20nd%20down.mp4"/>
</video>
<video controls>
  <source src="./up and down.mp4"/>
</video>
```

### 1. What work: Local

```html
import upAndDownURL from './up and down.mp4';

<video controls>
  <source src={upAndDownURL}/>
</video>
```

Careful ! `import upAndDownURL from './up%20and%20down.mp4';` will not work.

### 2. What work: Static/Public folder

`myVideo.avi` need to be put under `<project_root>/static` folder.

```html
<video controls>
  <source src="/myVideo.avi"/>
</video>
```

Comment: This also works with remote resources, i.e. - videos [uploaded through GitHub](https://github.blog/2021-05-13-video-uploads-available-github/). Just pass the generated URL to src.

Answer (score 1):

This is meant as a suggestion to the answer provided by @D.Kastier wich I myself used. @D.Kastier is using reactPlayer but was having problems with relavite paths and this is how i fixed it in my project:

> IMPORTANT
>
> I am having some trouble trying to render videos using relative path.

If you use the method described by @D.Kastier you will need to add import statements for the URLs of your videos and/or thumbnails.

```
import ReactPlayer from 'react-player'
import MyVideoUrl from './video/myVideo.mp4';
import MyThumbnailUrl from './video/myVideo.png';
```

and in the tag for Reactplayer you will use the imported URLs like so:

```
<ReactPlayer playing="true" controls url={MyVideoUrl} light={<img src={MyThumbnailUrl} alt='Thumbnail' />}/>
```

I´m using a Thumbnail for my videos and needed an URL for the video.

---

Altough it has few things to do with this answer this is also an useful import to have in your .mdx files

```
import useBaseUrl from '@docusaurus/useBaseUrl';
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a responsive option

Install `react-player` by running `npm install react-player`

In `intro.mdx`

```
---
slug: /
sidebar_position: 1
---
import ReactPlayer from "react-player"

<div className="video__wrapper">
    <ReactPlayer className="video__player" controls height="100%" url="https://storage.googleapis.com/files.school-app.bujus.de/school-instructions-v2-compressed.mp4" width="100%" />
</div>
```

In `custom.css`

```
.video__wrapper {
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 56.25%; /* Video aspect ratio: 100 / (16 / 9) */
}

.video__player {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

You may have to adjust the padding-bottom value. The formula to calculate it is besides the value.

When you want a break line below the video add `­{" "}` below the `</div>`.

You may want to add a thumbnail image with something like the following code:

```
config={{
  file: {
    attributes: {
      poster:
        "https://thumbnail.jpg",
    },
  },
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment, but just complementing the answer above, you can treat as an HTML file, so after the controls on `<video controls>`you can add width, height, style...

```
<video controls width="90%">
  <source src="/uploads/VideoName.mp4"/>
</video>
```

The video can be in any folder inside the `static` folder, but I've tried to go from that directory backwards and couldn't.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to add an iframe directly in mdx file

```
<iframe
  width="560"
  height="315"
  src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/lHu02MWIPUY"
  frameborder="0"
  allow="autoplay; encrypted-media"
  allowfullscreen>
</iframe>
```