# Docusaurus: is it possible to use components from NPM packages?

Tags: reactjs, docusaurus, chakra-ui

I'm currently getting started with Docusaurus.
I know that I can write custom components using mdx files (https://docusaurus.io/docs/markdown-features/react), but is it possible to install a React NPM package and use its components?

I tried this with ChakraUI:

```
import { Switch } from "@chakra-ui/react";

<Switch>{"test"}</Switch>
```

But just the word "test" is rendered.
Thanks for the help!

Comment: I have few experience with react... But I managed to add the `react-player`, see if this shine some light for you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69193176/5734097

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed, I just had to create a Root component (https://docusaurus.io/docs/using-themes#wrapper-your-site-with-root) and wrap it with ChakraProvider

Answer (score 0):

Follow the steps below to get e.g. Chakra UI working with Docusaurus:

1. Create a custom root, i.e. a file at /src/theme/Root.js
2. Copy and Paste the following code snippet:

```js
import React from "react";
import { ChakraProvider } from "@chakra-ui/react";

// Default implementation, that you can customize
export default function Root({children}) {
  return (
    <ChakraProvider>
      {children}
    </ChakraProvider>
  );
}
```

**Troubleshooting:**

1. `error - TypeError: React__namespace.useSyncExternalStore is not a function` -> `npm add react-dom@latest react@latest`
2. `Could not resolve dependency error peer react@...` -> `npm config set legacy-peer-deps true`
3. If still not working try deleting `.docusaurus` folder and reinstalling the contents of `node_modules`